# How to pass Secrets name in Lambda environment variable in Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless, terraform-modules

I am creating Aurora-Postgresql using terraform module "terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws". When `manage_master_user_password` is set to `true`, it creates a secrets in Secrets Manager.

```
module "rds" {   
  source                      = "terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws"   
  version                     = "8.0.2"   
  engine                      = var.rds_engine   
  engine_version              = var.rds_engine_version     
  name                        = "${var.tags.project}-${var.tags.environment}"
  manage_master_user_password = true
}
```

I am trying to use the output from that secrets to pass it on in one of my lambda environment variables as below:

```
environment_variables = {     
  DB_HOST_NAME               = module.rds.cluster_endpoint       
  DB_NAME                    = module.rds.cluster_database_name       
  DB_PORT                    = module.rds.cluster_port       
  DB_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_NAME = module.rds.cluster_master_user_secret   
}
```

However I get the following error.

```
 The given value is not suitable for
│ module.claims_coverage_app.module.lambda_backend_functions["retrieve-coverage-api"].var.environment_variables
│ declared at
│ .terraform/modules/claims_coverage_app.lambda_backend_functions/variables.tf:148,1-33:
│ element "DB_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_NAME": string required.
```

Apparently the `cluster_master_user_secret` prints out the following but no mention of name that i need to pass it into DB Credentials env variables.
Can you please advise how do I pass on the secrets name.

```
cluster_master_user_secret = [
  {
    kms_key_id     = ""
    secret_arn     = ""
    secret_status  = "active" 
   }, 
]
```

I need to use secrets name (created by aurora module) and pass it on as an environment variable in Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[aws_secretsmanager_secret][1]` data source where you pass in the `secret_arn` and that will resolve the name.

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "cluster_secret" {
   arn = module.rds.cluster_master_user_secret[0].secret_arn
}

...

environment_variables = {     
  DB_HOST_NAME               = module.rds.cluster_endpoint       
  DB_NAME                    = module.rds.cluster_database_name       
  DB_PORT                    = module.rds.cluster_port       
  DB_CREDENTIALS_SECRET_NAME = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.cluster_secret.name
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with the above solution, I am getting the following error.        │ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on ../../modules/claims-coverage/secrets.tf line 70, in data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "cluster_secret":
│   70:   arn = module.rds.cluster_master_user_secret.secret_arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.rds.cluster_master_user_secret is empty list of object
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "secret_arn" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?
╵

Comment: Did you run `terraform plan` prior to running `terraform apply`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know it's a list of objects. I wonder if it's to hold rotated secrets too? 
Try `arn = module.rds.cluster_master_user_secret[0].secret_arn` 
Meanwhile I'll check AWS's API to see why that's a list.

edit: I don't think it should be a list https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_MasterUserSecret.html

Comment: I tried this module and I managed to reproduce your error with one caveat. I have 1 item in that list of objects, for me it's not an empty list. 
I also had to set `master_username` on the module.

Comment: so in the output it does create the following but the same secret_arn is not picked when used in aws_secretsmanager .                                                 


```Plan: 0 to add, 3 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  ~ cluster_master_user_secret         = [
      - {
          - kms_key_id    = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:xxxxxxx"
          - secret_arn    = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxx:secret:rds!cluster-xxx"
          - secret_status = "active"
        },
    ] ```